# Why do I get "Linker command failed" error if I import my main target into my XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xctest

I'm trying to do some unit testing with Xcode, and I have some extensions in my main target I want to write tests for.

I try to import access to these with `@testable import MainProjectTarget` at the top of the `XCTestCase` subclass, but if I then try to run the tests, I get a `linker command failed with exit code 1` error. If I remove it, the tests run find (provided I don't try to access those extensions).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably also including them directly in the test target. Click on the files on question and check to see if the checkbox for the test target is checked on the right side in the inspector. Uncheck them and it should start working. Otherwise, post any other surrounding details with the error. It might be telling you exactly what is failing.

Comment: By them you mean the extensions? They're not included in the test target unfortunately, just the main target. The xctest files are included in the test target, but not the main target. I'm not sure what other surrounding details to provide, that's the only error given and the project is pretty rudimentary otherwise. I deleted the test target and re-added it back with the default settings even, and no luck.